# erasing elements from a vector (hackerrank)

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I'm a beginner in C++. I have tried to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/vector-erase/problem) but couldn't, thus I checked the solution afterwards but there are some lines I don't understand:

```cpp
v.erase(v.begin() + x - 1); // i want to know why the "-1" is put here
v.erase(v.begin() + b - 1, v.begin() + c - 1);
```

Here is the code:

```cpp
int main()
{
  int N, a, x, b, c;
  vector <int> v;
  cin >> N;
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
  {
    cin >> a;
    v.push_back(a);
  }
  cin >> x >> b >> c;
  v.erase(v.begin() + x - 1);
  v.erase(v.begin() + b - 1, v.begin() + c - 1);
  cout << v.size() << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << v[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem, as stated on HackerRank, assumes `1`-based indices (like R, Matlab). C++ does not, and starts from `0` instead. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question aims to make you familiar with 2 common syntax of vector erase method 
.
For deleting single element use ,

v.erase( *pass iterator pointing to the element that you want to erase*)

For example , `v.erase(v.begin())` will erase first element of the vector or in other words will erase element at position 0 of the vector.

Since here `v.begin()` is iterator to the first element of the vector , provided vector isn't empty .

Similarly ,

```
v.erase(v.begin() + x -1);
```

erases element at position x of the vector.

Now to erase a range in the vector , overloaded method of erase is used . It is used as follows ,

v.erase(iter1,iter2)

It will erase all the elements in the range of iter1 to iter2 but not including iter2 , that is elements in the range [iter2 , iter2) will be erased . Remember iter2 won't be erased .
Thus this code ,

```
v.erase(v.begin() + b - 1, v.begin() + c - 1);
```

will erase all the elements from index b to index c , but not including index c .

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the `- 1`s being asked in the question are due to the `x`, `b`, and `c` being 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cmath>           //Header section
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {  
    vector<int> v;            //initializing vector v
    int n,i,b,c,d,size,val;
    cin>>n;                   //no. of integers in vector v
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)          
    {
        cin>>val;
        v.push_back(val);     /*syntax for input elements in vector, "val" is the 
                                    element*/
    }
    cin>>b;   // input position of element to be erased

    cin>>c>>d;  //input range of elements to be erased

    v.erase(v.begin()+b-1); // func to be used to erase an element

    v.erase(v.begin()+c-1,v.begin()+d-1) // func used to erase a range

    size=v.size();
    cout<<size<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";  //leftover elements output
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's generally advisable to give descriptions for answers rather than just posting a block of code with comments. OP was simply asking about what `std::vector::erase` is doing, and why the `- 1` was used on the iterator arithmetic.

Comment: Hi @Himanshu -- thank you for the contribution. Can you add an explanation of what your code is doing to help future readers and the author?